# Jenkins & TFS plug in

Tags: .net, tfs, jenkins

I am triggering build from Jenkins. Source code is in TFS. Used TFS plugin to integrate.
When I trigger build, it creates work_space and update it, and give below error about certificate. Please advise !!!

======

All files are up to date.

```
FATAL: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TECoreException: 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   at com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.mappers.TECoreExceptionMapper.map(TECoreExceptionMapper.java:99)
   at com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.mappers.RegistrationExceptionMapper.map(RegistrationExceptionMapper.java:23)
   at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.registration.RegistrationData.newFromServer(RegistrationData.java:70)
   at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.registration.RegistrationClient.getRegistrationData(RegistrationClient.java:645)
   at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.registration.RegistrationClient.getRegistrationEntry(RegistrationClient.java:188)
   at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.registration.RegistrationClient.getRegistrationEntry(RegistrationClient.java:167)
   at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.webservices.IdentityManagementService.(IdentityManagementService.java:65)
   at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Project.getVCCHistory(Project.java:84)
   at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Project.getDetailedHistory(Project.java:128)
   at hudson.plugins.tfs.actions.CheckoutAction.checkout(CheckoutAction.java:56)
   at hudson.plugins.tfs.TeamFoundationServerScm.checkout(TeamFoundationServerScm.java:176)
   at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1254)
   at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:624)
   at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
   at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:530)
   at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1732)
   at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
   at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
   at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:234) 
Caused by: com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.exceptions.TransportException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequestInternal(SOAPService.java:744)
   at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequest(SOAPService.java:473)
   at ms.tfs.services.registration._03._RegistrationSoap12Service.getRegistrationEntries(_RegistrationSoap12Service.java:105)
   at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.registration.RegistrationData.newFromServer(RegistrationData.java:65) ... 16 more 
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
   at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
   at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
   at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:597)
   at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2518)
   at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1313)
   at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:508)
   at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:197)
   at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:464)
   at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:376)
   at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequestInternal(SOAPService.java:588) ... 19 more 
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
   at com.microsoft.tfs.core.config.httpclient.internal.DefaultX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(DefaultX509TrustManager.java:181)
   at sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source) ... 37 more 
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
   at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried AltF4_'s solution using plug-ins but didn't work either. Here is how the issue is resolved.

> If you're connecting to a server over SSL, the server's cert needs to
>   be trusted by Java. (Java uses a different certificate store than,
>   say, Windows.) You can use the keytool command to import your server's
>   certificate.
>
> Alternately, you can set the environment variable:
>   TF_ACCEPT_UNTRUSTED_CERTIFICATES=true
>
> In order to not verify the trust chain of SSL certificates.

Make sure to restart Jenkins service after setting the env variable.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a link to this in Jenkin's issue log and apparently downloading the following plugin will help the issue;- 
[Link to the plgin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Skip+Certificate+Check+plugin)

I found the issue from [HERE](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22082)

Hope this helps - let me know.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion !! apparently I am getting same error. this plug in didn't help :-(

Comment: i assume you restarted Jenkins after installing the plugin - yes ? @user3232823

Comment: yes, you are right. But I restarted Jenkins service not machine.

Comment: Restarted complete operating system, still same issue.